# Should I include all the levels for a categorical variable even if they are not significant?

Tags: linear-regression

Quite Recently, I have been trying to forecast a set of response variables using linear regression in R. The response variables have daily observations and should be forecasted for at least 45 coming days. The variation of the response variable over time is shown in the following figure. My explanatory variables include both continuous and categorical variables. I have a categorical variable with 12 levels(say months of the year). Results for the variable selection show that a few levels of this variable are significant. I was wondering if I should include all 12 levels for the final forecasting model or only the significant ones.

P.S. There are 500 different response variables and various levels of the aforementioned variable are significant for each of them.
R-square and Iormation criteria for both scenarios are almost the same, for both train and test datasets(>0.9).

The R procedure for both scenarios(all the variables not included):

1. fm=lm(y~x+as.factor(Month),data = train)
2. fm=lm(y~x+I(Month==3)+I(Month==4),data = train)

Thanks in advance.
[response variable over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dxSO.png)

I implemented both scenarios but dont know which one is better.